# How do I output a video that is over 600 fps on FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fps, framerate

I have two videos that I want to concatenate, one is 29.97 fps and the other is 30.41 fps. I'm trying to make it look perfect by making the frame rate 91138.77 fps, but it can only go up to 600 fps. How do I output a video over 600 fps?

Comment: Your real question is “How do I ‘seamlessly’ concatenate videos with different frame rates?”, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Comment: Time base and frame rate are not the same thing. If you converted a 30fps 1 hour video to 90000 fps it would play in 1.2 seconds. Surely that is not what you want.

Comment: OT: I know what causes the existence of 29.97 fps, but where does 30.41 fps occur "in the wild"?

Comment: The OP hasn't provided the log, so I don't know for sure, but here's some background: ffmpeg reports two values for framerate. One is the average frame rate (shown as `fps`), the other is the real base framerate (shown as `tbr`). The avg is what the label suggests i.e. `total duration / total frames` and the real base rate is the framerate needed to represent the smallest timestamp interval among frames. The avg and tbr is different when the stream is variable frame rate. Typically, smartphones, security cameras, live video encoders..etc will produce such streams.